# Typescript chaining with generic types

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, chaining

I am creating a validation library with javascript/typescript to use in personal projects. Everything was working well till I started to chain.

I need to basically pass the object type to the method and let the typescript handle the autocomplete/show error.

```
// This works
const arrSchema1 = array<Array<{
    id: number
    products: Array<{
        name: string
    }>
}>>(
    object({
        id: number(),
        products: array(
            object({
                name2: string() // Shows error as intended
            })
        )
    })
)
```

But the moment I chain the array with the min method the system stops working.

```
// This doesn't work
const arrSchema2 = array<Array<{
    id: number
    products: Array<{
        name: string
    }>
}>>(
    object({
        id: number(),
        products: array(
            object({
                name2: string() // Does not show error as intended
            })
        )
        .min(1)
    })
)
```

I am doing something wrong or is this not possible to do?

[Working Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=210&ssc=2&pln=195&pc=1#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhnAxgCwKYFsCG0BuBXAOwBNUAzASwNSKllrgGEB7ABwE8Ancgc2QBdoACkQBKaB1TwmeDt1QA6evWgAVZOXgJpHRKmiImJaBugAbcroLxq0QiQ7Q%20aaAFkAkirMXUVvaWnExgSOaMoAMm4MAKIAcgDKUfLoRNAUpnqUIXocTEwCROQSiHxMHGzQTKQhJlIyuo4SCkowcAAC5pbWrh70wFAkiKaYEtA%20eOjQcSgYmCpsLJLQAN600GtxKgBKbjEA4tAAvNAARPB8XATcxwA0q2sAQgDyj2FRAIIxhycARrnpmAQbndoDEAKoue5RTZfY4EcbfVAcIEwNbQD4ATRhALYyNRaM2mzemKOx2GHEwONuKLWj3uACkogxPCSmN8AFaoYq41EAETeKiiMKImD4qGOUAAvv1OUMRnx5npmARRQAPARHFbUoIkFUALmgcPQCI4AG5gRw8Ol4PrNXi8QBtADWqDY%20rOF24AF19QAxQjFchMAhmrUSkNh6WDYZ6eULaCbS2oH0EAA8ADVMKY8HojtjrtAANIur551QlghsAB8X0EOEz2f1GazqHzztdhZd%20dZbP1KjEB2rvyY-2DkdlMYV8cT6frOegpaL5VzFfzzPnFerGuBsdQ%20qmaCwcwW8BDeIImHQu4Q50o3FPqI0TfIRH1CfSyZnzfzi9Xlfva0veB4EwOQ3RvS5wxDAZx0cSdmHQFhyHSfcZiVChuC%20W1UQMZVUDVfUlVVPh-2gNsAH4wI9Ej4B0ZgSAo68PXtT0SJYEVkAY91b0gsdo1guMUKwKIOByBwty1NtKO44FEVEqSIMlKCZT4zBvndTBin0IYgMmaYsBTNwCBYPA%20GrLC1gkTAiCDUxygAfUoYy%20H1QynJI1T1M0nc9z02YFRPYEWByUVihsDzzg0gRAOA0DGOkrUgryTlRRScLyU0i10lfRMP2xZj8wAcgK-M8s9P9Aq4OtRWgOy63MYVRRI0AIC1WBoAABXY1JSn0GQJGVXBZ2BWA%20gS4LkpsNinHku8KqS0KUkyyRsvSZjWPGhaEFowwry4y41rmkKUugOQ%20BcSQYtQQRopA3bwO4EQZvW%20bjtOpts0XQRyJmx64oUsaXrCogiDfK7vN0g8-OPfNz0vGb80fTNnxWpMCHzHCiIIoMiN%20vbZq1ZrhrgFRySsfwOAmJaghKP7uCJ6BWjY8lKcTKd0npxnhgvfRsbwvgOaZ7m6o%20l0OYkPgZCsInRrxRKjpsCKydKdBQfgQQlpR9Hefw6BCL5-NhdQRcfpmg6AfllIDAQpDUFV4Rtec3WHdx%206zdljbjqtxDkN8wQlh53C1VbTstsQOiW2gKbkGgCUsetn3IbQngXaYljt0kPhBFhu6PQR%20AnxfNnUZTUtS43fMbtivHfqcDQSIRTATPIUg2D9AgAyDQRSH9N4RNNz0U-ivEvZtv3oAbpuW7bjvgglBjzLtCe%20Gb1v-WXoMGKHEcSIlGv1ACrU6ufEUrsNlyjJM37BMwYTRLNqVIF4kYox0%204-lQAFr4Mi-1XH9%20AWrHzHwRBNBf1ciZMy24FQ%20UhkeSQJFK45yHqiDWQgz7rjYP2Qc-9RyQAftBPiOEzh-2HB-Ag%20pv5OS%20FvMhlZBBYOgG-Uhn9fKUIgSGJ%20egX6aB5CfMBP8vi8NFIAtUwDQGsPAaZZYUCFgwJmHAg%20eJEFPXNImfUtZZz6mxAwmhAJwycIDsQhqV42G-yEagOhDDzH8KcuVR%20kACHP20poGI8JEQ2IgaMURxBxGQ1MZArU4Nr4KIQRdW6KitSoI0c2LRFYdE4P0Q45Sz8gzEMNMaChkjLGHGrK4o07iJE-zsQYncHVKp8N8l8L%202JqwADJpFahHgnGYcj9I1PtAVJpqBr4FTTngpSUYRhpUilpTAOlHjsmSnAogHiBBAJ8fGTkpQiApjxiVDcIjRQLNmQEvEllrIEFsjVeAyBMCyOgBMjkxQ4inIWP456FsEC%20WtGiESFIUz2jWWU8gVVum%20TKiRIh5w8DFFKIIJAkMXmXOSjcs5qB-EiAeRNS2TB45-MhmPDG%20tSIhyjjHOO3t0WoSDOhQe%200%20kPwMdwi5kzrmFKofMkBiyDAcBWV8mpmyxE0quXwaZOyGl4iCb5EJwJlG0yRZtVBoNcormgEVdZVZAWpOBaCjg4Lnn6mhdc258KskVzCXITi91EWSipcqiotLHamK8VsplmwlmstWfdBVlY6EQpmFCy1sK7mSPzP7e07U7IAEYgjQCiCqQYeASApjbJUaAvrljQADaG2NVRJHenjT-ANnobVcunuvYIAAfSYqA%20Alw3NAYtLgznlrYC66AZEOrQH1FQHAiITQxydC6ON6bKwZskQG4NLEY6Vn1UBW6RqPSVtsMQMglBqAMK1XwHZHCkmDK4c4yY91ZlfDxpy7Z9LPELyFbA-yoTx1V3uiRKJ6DtE5JIdvYEQKLSquuga1Ak7bwmrwWaqwAg8aZIEUcPd9D71xG3Ye0yq7HETjjD6JCooOAKJTCoVc-lNxCAXsmzIqbVAZpUNm3NCyFENqbS21AbbTSShEF2tgcaVB9Jg-xPQ8HTCIcMkfIgyGVAYceOgcgZbUPQFY4h7j%20Z82BiLSWstNTp3VpYLWl1rqBkwVKUu718KACKRG7UOrZc6jBo6yxHBE4iDjSMuP%20RTJp11mFgT2gLCm7tVQGMMQ0yhhzALFIlMnG4eA4bIq2TeBWFDGHdHBEZZoQQnhIsGgo4iUjwK9D6lIJmawYhG1JebakNLqAVN8VKe5njXw-MBeKEFkLxXYtZcbdUit%20p7TAhUFAHNsX7SlRzY23u5I2Bf2Kw14E5iWs6c0PaBjpHrGsP60mprw22vdmSp17lMKpvVgG1qdJiI5veKZWNpbeTjR9bWzNrUeNtu2tG%20N2rEG-HTca1qcL52uV7dI0wkcR3stHfy3KSc3WKRFZGxg5iGGCObY4K1nbmg-tsBTMejOLa3FUcCRnINESJTVlqzqjzYOyqfax6DxHXn7FMepdDvlkHAelX3Uy-lC99k2XsicuF%20pofuayRK467qsD6nauU0U18SInvkWe0V76Inu0BotNRRcZVsHynK4qQOifD2VS%20koaqueYBZ283rWOsnfol48rp19MUO2DnWyOXVY5OzRdfJOD1%206JKpZu1nFPYtU8B2ThUMzIO7NRELw8IutRirxhzmwUqcqplKoVRXVOlV-rV2CzX2uets6KWOy6n7LgG9RITVqjA0CIEdJoZu0B%20PBDBxUKoqB0iXmVPAAWXMJjl-eqgRvzMy-voZqwAtFzKNcBIJoEgqXLRRXffTJYSw2wSglNAAA7khUw49sioBYEMeoC%20nC9REj4AQbZpaisoNdSgreEf5I4BnidJtqiKNRIQcgABHbMb6L0fuv7XA%20%20DklcPNWSCkgGGVIclc3UNVXlU89d09O9X8s8MJi07A50qAiAGFXc-F2coB0DIBgBgBVB9559Shi8oAgV5wRJr4Q1cwdcUxodYcoAABIZGA0RHWgxKIgEFPgF5KgzUGgmg7OGaWg9HSUV1QQWghbYoP2WgugwuMHehKkLg5g1gl5P-NgIQyALgmgkQzOTg1Q7OAAJhmnoXEJoN3nEJED4JMMgDMIwKwJwJMGskkAIAKn5kgCILJGvm0JLAoI4NoPoLByYJyBYOKHYIoM0J4Npj4MrAELoWEMtTEJUIkLP2NGkPELkICK0R12UNUPUJiNUO4IvFQF0Npn0NiMMLMK4JKJoKSCPyDRKKMPMKAA)

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible example. Also, don;t rely on your "Working Example" link, since it might don't work in future. Consider creating minimum exmaple and paste it into your question

Comment: I think this is due to the fact of where inference is supposed to occur from. For the first example, inference will occur from the return type for `Input`. This is fine. TS can do this. For the example with `min`, TS doesn't even know what to check for `min` until it known what `min` is, so it first infers for `array`, but has no way to know how the return type of `min` will impact `array` (since it has no idea what `min` is yet) so it infers for `array` without the return type info, resulting in the loss of type info. Try creating a different api if you want this to work with TS

Comment: This might work better: `declare const array: <Input extends any[]>(schemas: ArrayShape<Input>, message?: string | undefined, sub?: (c: ArraySchema<Input>) => void) => ArraySchema<Input>;`. Then the `min` validation can be called in a fucntion passed to `sub` where type info is available

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I thought of doing that as well, and it is a good idea, but I see the chain ways as a better approach and I really wanted to do that way.

Comment: @captain-yossarian I am sorry but an example on the question would be too big, that is why I tried to give one with the link.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I believe the problem is that with array, typescript will inject the type on the generic because it is the first "method" but with "min", "min" became the first "method" so typescript is trying to inject